# How to make webdriver wait and what statement does it?

Tags: java, selenium, webdriver

Does the first line alone make webdriver wait for 10 seconds? or do I need to have both?

```
 WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver,10);
 wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathID)));
```

I'm confused about what statement makes driver wait?Is this statement enough?

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver,10);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three distinct wait mechanisms `Selenium` provides so far I know. `Explicit`,`Implicit` and `Fluent`. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658418/differences-between-impilicit-explicit-and-fluentwait/28661840#28661840). The one you have mentioned is `Explicit`. Explicit wait is meant to wait for element to meet certain condition you tell the `WebDriver`. Such as element's visibility(the one you are using),element exists etc. There is a class in `org.openqa.selenium.support.ui` named `ExpectedConditions` that has good number of members to provide different mechanism for waiting for the element.See [here](https://selenium.googlecode.com/git/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) for a complete list.

Going back to your question:
`WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver,10);` only defines the wait and the length `WebDriver` should wait to meet *condition* provided by you(in second line.)
The actual wait happens `wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathID)));`.
`WebDriver` tries to find the element matching the `xpathID` and it's visibilty on the page and after `10s` it throws exception. If `WebDriver` finds the target element before `10s` it will not wait `10s` and move forward.

Comment: best explanation to my question!

Answer (score 1):

```
WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(firefoxDriver,10);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath(xpathID)));
```

Wait will ignore instances of **NotFoundException** that are encountered (thrown) by default in the 'until' condition, and immediately propagate all others.

You can add more to the ignore list by calling ignoring(exceptions to add) method.