# How to use built-in ExpectedConditions with FluentWait?

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, fluentwait

In Selenium (Java), I want to use ExpectedConditions with FluentWait. I am trying out following code which is not working. It is not waiting for the element to appear in the DOM.

Could someone please help here ?

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("mybutton")));
```

Note: I have tried this with WebDriverWait and it is working file. I am trying with FluentWait since I want to control polling timeout.

Comment: are you using fluent and explicit wait same time ?

Comment: try only `Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver)
                    .withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("mybutton")));`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually it was my bad. Please ignore second statement. I have removed that and edited question. I was using it correctly. This doesn't work. This doesn't honor the timeout of 10 seconds. The call comes out immediately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A bit of background :

### Fluent Wait

[**`Fluent Wait`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) is the implementation of the [**`Wait`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/Wait.html) interface which an user can configure its timeout and polling interval on the fly. A **`FluentWait`** instance defines the maximum amount of time to wait for a condition along with the frequency with which to check the condition. The user can also configure the wait to ignore specific types of exceptions while waiting, such as `NoSuchElementExceptions` when searching for an element on the page.

### WebDriverWait

[**`WebDriverWait`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/WebDriverWait.html) is the tailor-made version of [FluentWait](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/FluentWait.html) that uses WebDriver instances.

You can find a detailed discussion on **`WebDriverWait`** and **`FluentWait`** in both of these QA [**`Implicit vs Explicit vs Fluent Wait`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145111/implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait/48162909#48162909) and [**`Differences between impilicit, explicit and fluentwait`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658418/differences-between-impilicit-explicit-and-fluentwait).

### ExpectedConditions

[**`ExpectedConditions`**](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) are the tailor made canned conditions which are generally useful within webdriver tests.

---

As per your question, as you are `trying with FluentWait since you want to control polling timeout` you can still achieve the same through **`WebDriverWait`** as follows :

- **`WebDriverWait`** have 3 **Constructors** and one of them is :

  ```
  WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)
  ```
- Details :

  ```
  public WebDriverWait(WebDriver driver, long timeOutInSeconds, long sleepInMillis)

  This wait will ignore instances of NotFoundException that are encountered by default in the `until` condition, and immediately propagate all others. You can also add more to the ignore list by calling ignoring(exceptions to add).

  Parameters:
  driver - The WebDriver instance to pass to the expected conditions
  timeOutInSeconds - The timeout in seconds when an expectation is called
  sleepInMillis - The duration in milliseconds to sleep between polls (polling interval).
  ```

### Solution :

You can use the above mentioned **Constructor** of **`WebDriverWait`** and still can control the polling interval.

> **Note** : To keep your program logic simple and understandable use **`WebDriverWait`** instead of **`Fluent Wait`** untill and unless absolute necessary.

### Trivia :

For further understanding of **`Fluent Wait`** you can follow the discussion [**`Selenium Webdriver 3.0.1-[Eclipse-Java-Chrome]: Selenium showing error for FluentWait Class`**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42275658/selenium-webdriver-3-0-1-eclipse-java-chrome-selenium-showing-error-for-fluen)

Comment: If I use WebDriver wait, I won't be able to use canned expected conditions. I need to use them with ability of polling.

Comment: See the constructor I have provided in my answer and the link to the JavaDoc. You too can do it. See the discussions I have linked. Let me know if you need further help.

Comment: Got it Thanks. My bad. The constructor was already there in webdriver wait. So supposedly ExpectedConditions should be always used with WebDriverWait and not FluentWait class.

Answer (score 0):

Yes what NarendraR said is correct. When you have created object for FluentWait used the same object for write ExpectedConditions.

```
Wait<WebDriver> wait = new FluentWait<WebDriver>(driver).withTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS).pollingEvery(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
wait.unitl(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("mybutton")));
```

Comment: There is a typo in the second line. It has to read
`wait.until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("mybutton")));`