# How can I get the count of links/items in yahoo home page top panel?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, xpath, css-selectors

```
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/");
driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
List<WebElement> optionCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mega-bottombar\"]"));
System.out.println(optionCount.size());
```

[count im trying to get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dctNA.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are trying to get the count of items in yahoo top panel just after invoking `get()` method you have to induce *WebDriverWait* and you can use the following code block :

```
driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/");
List<WebElement> optionCount = new WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("//div[@id='mega-bottombar']/ul//li/a")));
System.out.println(optionCount.size());
```

Console Output :

```
9
```

**Note** : The link with text as **Cricket** seems to be missing from your snapshot you have provided.

[image: yahoo]

Comment: Why we driver is needed ? He is using implicit wait,no?

Comment: @Rajagopalan _explicitwait_ is much more optimized with respect to _implicit wait_

Comment: @Rajagopalan Check the discussions [What is the internal working difference between Implicit Wait and Explicit Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46365040/what-is-the-internal-working-difference-between-implicit-wait-and-explicit-wait/46398760#46398760), [Implicit vs Explicit vs Fluent Wait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48145111/implicit-vs-explicit-vs-fluent-wait/48162909#48162909), [Differences between impilicit, explicit and fluentwait](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28658418/differences-between-impilicit-explicit-and-fluentwait/48323031#48323031)

Answer (score 0):

This will return a list of the menu items:

```
List<WebElement> list = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id="mega-bottombar"]//li"));
```

So... `list.size()` returns 8, which according to your comment is what you're after.

Comment: driver.get("https://www.yahoo.com/");

        driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

        List<WebElement> optionCount = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"mega-bottombar\"]"));
        System.out.println(optionCount.size());

trying this still not getting all the elements